# Why does foldl seems to be harmful despite being tail-recursive?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fold

I've always believed that tail-recursive functions are better in terms of
performance than non tail-recursive versions. So, counting items in a list *might* be implemented like so:

```
count:: [a] -> Int
count [] = 0
count (x:xs) = 1 + count xs
```

But this function is not tail recursive, and so is not as performant as possible. The fix is to *accumulate* counts, like so:

```
_count:: Num b => b -> [a] -> b
_count b [] = b
_count b (x:xs) = _count (b + 1) xs

count:: [a] -> Int
count = _count 0
```

This can be easily implemented with a tail-recursive fold:

```
myfold:: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
myfold f b [] = b
myfold f b (x:xs) = myfold f (f b x) xs

count = myfold incr 0
   where incr c _ = c + 1
```

But, then I remembered something about left vs right folds.  It turned out
`myfold` is a left fold, which according to Real World Haskell shouldn't be used:

> This is convenient for testing, but we will never use foldl in practice.

...because of the thunking of the application of `f b x`.

So, I tried to rewrite `myfold` as a right fold:

```
myfoldr:: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
myfoldr f b [] = b
myfoldr f b (x:xs) = f x (myfoldr f b xs)
```

But that's not tail-recursive.

It seems, then, that Haskell non-strict evaluation makes tail-recursiveness
less important.  Yet, I have this feeling that for *counting* items in lists a strict `foldl` should perform better than any `foldr`, because there's no way we can extract anything from an `Integer`.

To sum up, I think these are the better implementations (using folds) for map and count:

```
map:: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f = foldr g []
  where g x fxs = (f x):fxs

count:: [a] -> Int
count = foldl incr 0
  where incr c _ = c + 1
```

Is this correct?

Comment: IIRC, the reason that RWH states that we'll never use `foldl` in practice is because you should use `foldl'` instead.

Comment: If you are using a left fold to produce a lazy data structure (which, in particular, you need to consume lazily, typically because it's too large to manifest in memory) *and* you need to do some computation in between each step which you want to perform immediately - not when the result is actually evaluated - then using `foldl` is appropriate. But these are very restrictive conditions, so in practice, `foldl` is never used.

Comment: A rough guideline is: if your fold returns some type which is represented in constant-space (e.g. `Int`), prefer `foldl'` so that the whole fold requires constant space. Otherwise, if the return type is a lazy list/tree/whatever, prefer `foldr`, so that it can be consumed lazily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It seems, then, that Haskell non-strict evaluation makes tail-recursiveness less important. Yet, I have this feeling that for counting items in lists a strict `foldl` should perform better than any `foldr`, because there's no way we can extract anything from an `Integer`.

That is correct, and tail-calls *are* more efficient. But this benefit can be outweighed by the cost of creating large thunks, and this is the case for `foldl`.

The way to have your cake and eat it too is to make sure that the accumulator is not thunked, but rather eagerly evaluated:

```
myfold:: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
myfold f !b [] = b
myfold f !b (x:xs) = myfold f (f b x) xs
```

Which is, of course, the `foldl'` function.

TL;DR: Never use `foldl`, but do use `foldl'`.

Comment: It is debatable whether this bang-pattern version of `myfold` is actually tail-recursive, as seems to be implied by "have your cake and eat it too". [The documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) says it should behave the same as the bang-pattern free ```myfold f b (x:xs) = b `seq` myfold f (f b x) xs```, which is not tail-recursive.

Comment: That is still tail-recursive, as `seq` returns the return value of its second argument.